# Keep the row for which the values of two columns match by group otherwise keep the first row by group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to left join df2 on df1 and then keep the row that matches by group and if there is no matching group then I would like to keep the first row of the group in order to achieve df3 (the desired result). I was hoping you guys could help me with finding the optimal solution.

Here is my code to create the two dataframes and the required result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

market = ['SP', 'SP', 'SP']
underlying = ['TSLA', 'GOOG', 'MSFT']
  
# DF1
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(market, underlying)),
               columns=['market', 'underlying'])

market2 = ['SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP']
underlying2 = [None, 'TSLA', 'GBX', 'GBM', 'GBS']
client2 = [17, 12, 100, 21, 10]

# DF2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(market2, underlying2, client2)),
               columns=['market', 'underlying', 'client'])

market3 = ['SP', 'SP', 'SP']
underlying3 = ['TSLA', 'GOOG', 'MSFT']
client3 = [12, 17, 17]

# Desired
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(market3, underlying3, client3)),
               columns =['market', 'underlying', 'client'])

# This works but feels sub optimal
df3 = pd.merge(df, 
               df2,
               how='left',
               on=['market', 'underlying'])
df3 = pd.merge(df3, 
               df2,
               how='left',
               on=['market'])
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(['market', 'underlying_x'])
df3['client'] = df3['client_x'].combine_first(df3['client_y'])
df3 = df3.drop(labels=['underlying_y', 'client_x', 'client_y'], axis=1)
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'underlying_x': 'underlying'})
```

Hope you guys could help, thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the first value (a groupby might not be necessary if every single one in market is 'SP'), merge and fill with the first value:

```py
fill_value = df2.groupby('market').client.first()

# if you are interested in filtering for None:
fill_value = df2.set_index('market').loc[lambda df: df.underlying.isna(), 'client']


(df
.merge(
    df2, 
    on = ['market', 'underlying'], 
    how = 'left')
.set_index('market')
.fillna({'client':fill_value}, downcast='infer')
)

       underlying  client
market                   
SP           TSLA      12
SP           GOOG      17
SP           MSFT      17
```

Comment: I ordered the dataframe in order to have the null value always at the top, hence this works very well. Is there also a possibility to choose the row which has None for the value underlying rather than the first one? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: updated code to filter for `None`